# windows 8.1 phone application validation error while uploading to store: we cant read the package

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, wack

I am trying to upload windows 8.1 phone application ("app x upload") on windows phone store  and getting  validation error while uploading to store: we cant read the package. local validation has been passed through windows app certification kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

> **Project** -> **Store** -> **Associate App with the Store.**

and then **Rebuild Solution** .

Comment: What is the size of your package ?

Comment: Whts the matter of size. My package is of 480kb

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem.